# Disable buttons for 2 seconds in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button

This code is for a website that prompts the user to click on which event they think happened first. After the user makes their guess the year is presented under the buttons for 2 seconds. I am trying to make it so for those 2 seconds the buttons cant be clicked because you can spam click the right answer and it racks up a bunch of points.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Invention Game</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url("https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/newscms/2019_18/1432153/cinco-de-mayo-celebrations-today-main-190501.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
      }
      
      #game-board {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
      
      button {
        font-size: 2.4em;
        margin: 70px;
        padding: 30px;
        /* ========= add this to keep the whitespace to that the new line shows properly ========== */
        white-space: pre;
      }
      
      /* added styles for the h1 element */
      h1 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding: 20px 20px 10px 10px;


      }

      h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

      
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1><center>What happened first?</center></h1>
    <div id="game-board">
      <h2>Score: <span id="score">0</span></h2>
      <div>
        <button id="item1"></button>
        <button id="item2"></button>
      </div>
    </div> 


    <script>
      // generate a list of items and their corresponding years
      const itemList = [
        { item: "The Battle Of Puebla", year: 1862 },
        { item: "Mexican Independance Declared", year: 1821 },
        { item: "The Mexican Peso becoming the official currency of mexico", year: 1823 },
        { item: "The First Commercial Flight by a Mexican Airline", year: 1921},
        { item: "The Establishing of the Bank Of Mexio", year: 1925},
        { item: "The First Celebration of Cinco De Mayo in the USA", year: 1863},
        { item: "The Mexican Revolution", year: 1910},
        { item: "The DISCOVERY of Machu Picchu", year: 1911},


        // add more items and years as needed
      ];

      // randomly select two items from the list
      let item1, item2;
      function selectItems() {
        item1 = itemList[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemList.length)];
        item2 = itemList[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemList.length)];
        
        // make sure item1 and item2 are not the same item
        while (item1.item === item2.item) {
          item2 = itemList[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemList.length)];
        }
      }
      selectItems();

      // display the items on the game board
      const item1Btn = document.getElementById("item1");
      const item2Btn = document.getElementById("item2");
      item1Btn.textContent = item1.item;
      item2Btn.textContent = item2.item;
      

      // add event listener to the buttons
      let score = 0;
      item1Btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (item1.year < item2.year) {
          // user was correct
          score++;
          document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
        } else {
          // user was incorrect
          score = 0;
          document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
          alert("Incorrect!");
        }
        
        //  ======== display the year on both buttons, \n is a new line so that it shows below the text===========
        item1Btn.textContent += '\n Year is: ' + item1.year;
        item2Btn.textContent += '\n Year is: ' + item2.year;
      
        // ========== Wait 2 seconds and then change the text to the next one
        // so that the year can be seen by the user, and not changed instantly ===========
        setTimeout(() => {
            selectItems();
          item1Btn.textContent = item1.item;
            item2Btn.textContent = item2.item;
        }, 2000);
      });

      item2Btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (item2.year < item1.year) {
          // user was correct
          score++;
          document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
        } else {
          // user was incorrect
          score = 0;
          document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
          alert("Incorrect!");
        }
        
        //  ======== display the year ===========
        item1Btn.textContent += '\n Year is: ' + item1.year;
        item2Btn.textContent += '\n Year is: ' + item2.year;
      
        // ========== Wait 2 seconds and then change the text to the next one
        // so that the year can be seen by the user, and not changed instantly ===========
        setTimeout(() => {
            selectItems();
          item1Btn.textContent = item1.item;
            item2Btn.textContent = item2.item;
        }, 2000);
      });

      // add event listener to the play again button
      // ============= your play again button is not found, so it will error, so you should add it ===============
      const playAgainBtn = document.getElementById("play-again");
      playAgainBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        score = 0;
        document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
        selectItems();
        item1Btn.textContent = item1.item;
        item2Btn.textContent = item2.item;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use this code to disable the buttons but it just made them disappear and messed up the website

```
<script>
function disableButton() {
  document.getElementById("item1Btn").disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = false;
  }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

I used this code for button 1 and 2 each time the year is displayed but when i ran the code nothing appeared in the buttons and nothing would happen when i clicked on them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you sure you want to disable `item1Btn` but enable `myButton`?

Comment: just add or toggle a class /  or the css styles `pointer-events: none` aaaaaaand done.

Comment: (to add onto Marcin's comment, don't even query select twice: capture the element in a variable, and then set thatvar.disabled to true and then 2 seconds later, to false)

Comment: `disableButton()` is a function, but your example code never calls it. If you need help debugging code, it's important to include all relevant code, and the code that calls your function is very relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *`disable="true"`* the button after the user click on the answer.

```js
const itemList = [
      { item: "The Battle Of Puebla", year: 1862 },
      { item: "Mexican Independance Declared", year: 1821 },
      { item: "The Mexican Peso becoming the official currency of mexico", year: 1823 },
      { item: "The First Commercial Flight by a Mexican Airline", year: 1921},
      { item: "The Establishing of the Bank Of Mexio", year: 1925},
      { item: "The First Celebration of Cinco De Mayo in the USA", year: 1863},
      { item: "The Mexican Revolution", year: 1910},
      { item: "The DISCOVERY of Machu Picchu", year: 1911},


      // add more items and years as needed
   ];

   // randomly select two items from the list
   let item1, item2;
   function selectItems() {
      item1 = itemList[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemList.length)];
      item2 = itemList[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemList.length)];
      
      // make sure item1 and item2 are not the same item
      while (item1.item === item2.item) {
         item2 = itemList[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemList.length)];
      }
   }
   selectItems();

   // display the items on the game board
   const item1Btn = document.getElementById("item1");
   const item2Btn = document.getElementById("item2");
   item1Btn.textContent = item1.item;
   item2Btn.textContent = item2.item;
   

   // add event listener to the buttons
   let score = 0;
   item1Btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (item1.year < item2.year) {
         // user was correct
         score++;
         document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
         item1Btn.disabled = true;
         item2Btn.disabled = true;
      } else {
         // user was incorrect
         score = 0;
         document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
         alert("Incorrect!");
         item1Btn.disabled = true;
         item2Btn.disabled = true;
      }
      
      //  ======== display the year on both buttons, \n is a new line so that it shows below the text===========
      item1Btn.textContent += '\n Year is: ' + item1.year;
      item2Btn.textContent += '\n Year is: ' + item2.year;
   
      // ========== Wait 2 seconds and then change the text to the next one
      // so that the year can be seen by the user, and not changed instantly ===========
      setTimeout(() => {
         selectItems();
         item1Btn.textContent = item1.item;
         item2Btn.textContent = item2.item;
         item1Btn.disabled = false;
         item2Btn.disabled = false;
      }, 2000);
   });

   item2Btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (item2.year < item1.year) {
         // user was correct
         score++;
         document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
         item1Btn.disabled = true;
         item2Btn.disabled = true;
      } else {
         // user was incorrect
         score = 0;
         document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
         alert("Incorrect!");
         item1Btn.disabled = true;
         item2Btn.disabled = true;
      }
      
      //  ======== display the year ===========
      item1Btn.textContent += '\n Year is: ' + item1.year;
      item2Btn.textContent += '\n Year is: ' + item2.year;
   
      // ========== Wait 2 seconds and then change the text to the next one
      // so that the year can be seen by the user, and not changed instantly ===========
      setTimeout(() => {
         selectItems();
         item1Btn.textContent = item1.item;
         item2Btn.textContent = item2.item;
         item1Btn.disabled = false;
         item2Btn.disabled = false;
      }, 2000);
   });

   // add event listener to the play again button
   // ============= your play again button is not found, so it will error, so you should add it ===============
   const playAgainBtn = document.getElementById("play-again");
   playAgainBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      score = 0;
      document.getElementById("score").textContent = score;
      selectItems();
      item1Btn.textContent = item1.item;
      item2Btn.textContent = item2.item;
   });
```

```css
body {
   background-image: url("");
   background-size: cover;
}

#game-board {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
}

button {
   font-size: 2.4em;
   margin: 70px;
   padding: 30px;
   /* ========= add this to keep the whitespace to that the new line shows properly ========== */
   white-space: pre;
}

/* added styles for the h1 element */
h1 {
   font-size: 2.5em;
   background-color: #ccc;
   padding: 20px 20px 10px 10px;


}

h2 {
   font-size: 2em;
   background-color: #ccc;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;


}
```

```html
<h1><center>What happened first?</center></h1>
<div id="game-board">
  <h2>Score: <span id="score">0</span></h2>
  <div>
    <button id="item1"></button>
    <button id="item2"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```